# How to whitelist Cypress front-end testing in CloudFlare WAF?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, cloudflare

When developing automated Cypress front-end testing, I have allowed local static IPs to bypass Cloudflare's bot detection in their WAF. Though, this is not the most sustainable solution. I have thought using [HTTP request header fields](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ruleset-engine/rules-language/fields/#http-request-header-fields) filter in Cloudflare and then [adding some header](https://www.webtips.dev/webtips/cypress/add-headers-to-every-request-in-cypress) to each Cypress test, but not sure does that follow the best practices either.